# date validation using regular expression in pig - getting ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias

Tags: regex, date, datetime, apache-pig

I have sampledata.csv which contains data as below,

2,4/1/2010,5.97

2,4/6/2010,12.71

2,4/7/2010,34.52

2,4/12/2010,7.89

2,4/14/2010,17.17

2,4/16/2010,9.25

2,4/19/2010,26.74

I want to filter the data in pig script so that only data with valid date are considered.
Say if the date is like '4//2010' or '/9/2010', then it has to be filtered out.

Below is the pig script I have written and the output I am getting while dumping the data.

script:

```
data = load 'sampledata.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (custid:int, date:chararray,amount:float);

cleadata = FILTER data by REGEX_EXTRACT(date, '(([1-9])|(1[0-2]))/(([0-2][1-9])|([3][0-1]))/([1-9]{4})', 1) != null;
```

Output:

```
2014-09-14 18:21:30,587 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias cleandata
```

I am a beginner in pig scripting. If you have come across this kind of error,please let me know how to resolve.

Comment: Is it because of the typo `cleadata`?

Answer (score 1):

here the solution for your problem. I have modified the Regex also, if you want you can change the regex according to your need.

input.txt

```
2,04/1/0000,5.97
2,04/1/2010,5.97
2,44/6/2010,12.71
2,4/07/2010,34.52
2,4/\12/2010,7.89
2,4/14/2010/,17.17
2,/16/2010,9.25
2,4/19//2010,26.74
2,4//19/2010,26.74

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (custid:int,date:chararray,amount:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(date, '(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|0?[1-9])/([1-2][0-9]{3})')) AS (month,day,year);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE CONCAT(month,'/',day,'/',year) AS extractedDate;
D = FILTER C BY extractedDate is not null;
DUMP D;

Output:
(04/1/2010)
(4/07/2010)
```